# Poblar con ceros números faltantes en un array enviado de un formulario php

Tags: php, array, bucle-for, foreach

Tengo un script en PHP, que al ejecutarlo me envía esta información por post y poblar con ceros los numeros faltantes hasta el numero 10

```
$checkbox1[] = 1;
$checkbox1[] = 3;
$checkbox1[] = 5;

$chk="";
foreach($checkbox1 as $chk1)  
 {  
 $chk .= $chk1.", ";  
 }

echo $chk;
```

Este codigo imprime:

```
1, 3, 5,
```

Lo que deseo es poblar con ceros los numeros faltantes hasta el 10 y que imprima lo siguiente

```
1,0,3,0,5,0,0,0,0,0
```

Hasta completar los 10 numeros

Gracias por sus respuestas

Comment: Creo que podrías crear primero un array con los diez números a 0. Luego, recorres los checkbox y en aquel que tienes valor, cambias al número.

Comment: Lo que dice @Jakala es una buena opción y también la más recomendable, aparte es menos código innecesario

Comment: Gracias por las respuestas, no logro plasmarlo, podrian realizar un ejemplo por favor

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que tu información esta guardada como lo has puesto el la pregunta en el arreglo checkbox....

1. Crea el array $my_array inicializándolo a 0
2. Copia tus valores del array original al nuevo en los indexes pertinentes

   ```
   <?php

    $checkbox1[] = 1;
    $checkbox1[] = 3;
    $checkbox1[] = 5;

    $my_array = array_fill(0, 10, 0);
    //print_r($my_array);

   foreach ( $checkbox1 as $value){
       $my_array[$value-1] = $value;
   }

   print_r($my_array);
   ?>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

La siguiente función resuelve tu problema, y puede utilizarse para rellenar con valores diferentes de 0 los espacios vacíos y series de números de *n* tamaño.

#### Código

```
<?php

function fillIntermediateArrNumbers(
    array $arr,
    int $limit = 10,
    $fillWith = 0
): array {
    $compareWith = 1;

    $result = [];
    while ($compareWith <= $limit) {
        $result[] = (in_array($compareWith, $arr))
            ? $compareWith
            : $fillWith;

        $compareWith++;
    }


    return $result;
}

// Test:
$arr1 = [1, 4, 6, 7];
$arr2 = [4, 6, 7, 10];
$arr3 = [4, 6, 7, 10,15,16];
print_r(fillIntermediateArrNumbers($arr1));
print_r(fillIntermediateArrNumbers($arr2));
print_r(fillIntermediateArrNumbers($arr3, 20));
print_r(fillIntermediateArrNumbers($arr3, 20, 'x'));
```

#### Resultados:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 0
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 7
    [7] => 0
    [8] => 0
    [9] => 0
)
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 0
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 7
    [7] => 0
    [8] => 0
    [9] => 10
)
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 0
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 7
    [7] => 0
    [8] => 0
    [9] => 10
    [10] => 0
    [11] => 0
    [12] => 0
    [13] => 0
    [14] => 15
    [15] => 16
    [16] => 0
    [17] => 0
    [18] => 0
    [19] => 0
)
Array
(
    [0] => x
    [1] => x
    [2] => x
    [3] => 4
    [4] => x
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 7
    [7] => x
    [8] => x
    [9] => 10
    [10] => x
    [11] => x
    [12] => x
    [13] => x
    [14] => 15
    [15] => 16
    [16] => x
    [17] => x
    [18] => x
    [19] => x
)
```

#### Explicación

La función recibe por defecto un array con algunos números y rellena con el valor indicado, `$fillWith` los huecos entre ellos hasta llegar al número indicado como `$limite`, buscando desde el número 1.

Para obtener el array que necesitas solo tienes que pasarle como parámetro tu array.